# SSL Error in Facebook app

Tags: angularjs, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-graph-api, ssl

I have created one Facebook app using AngularJs. It was working fine from long time. Suddenly it started showing an error.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/platform/page_proxy/hv09mZVdEP8.js#app_runner_fb_https561de0847b9875818384110
```

link of a [sample page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/GUP/766425153419408?sk=app_1429717347289557). I can add a security exception in browser and then I'm good to go. But, I'm looking for a permanent fix. Not sure how to get rid of it. Any ideas?

Comment: I don’t see any such error anywhere, when going to the page you mentioned in Firefox. // If that error originates from the request to `https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/…`, then it likely means this is (/was) something Facebook has to fix on their end – might be as simple as an expired certificate for that particular subdomain.

Comment: @CBroe: I also think that..it's Facebook issue. Nobody has reported such issue. And error was showing in Chrome. In Firefox, it's showing that 'This Connection is Untrusted...'  message.